# How can I tag an AWS Lambda function using boto3

Tags: aws-lambda, boto3

I have code that creates a boto3 client of type 'lambda'. I then use that client to call the list_functions(), create_function(), and update_function() methods. That all works well as outlined in this documentation:
http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.list_functions

But when i go to use the list_tags() or tag_resource() methods outline here:
http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.list_tags

I get an error saying:

> AttributeError: 'Lambda' object has no attribute 'list_tags'

what am I doing wrong? Those methods are listed on the same doc page so I figure they are called on the same client. What gives:

```
    l = boto3.client(
    'lambda',
    region_name='us-east-1', 
    aws_access_key_id = 'AletitgoQ',
    aws_secret_access_key = 'XvHowdyW',
)
    l.list_tags(
         Resource="myArn"
        )        

    l.tag_resource(
            Resource="myArn",
            Tags={
                'action': 'test'
          }
      )
```

To make matters worse, I don't appear to be able to include the tags in the create_function() call despite what the docs say about that here:
http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.create_function

when i include tags in the call i get this response:

> botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
>   Unknown parameter in input: "Tags", must be one of: FunctionName, Runtime, Role, Handler, Code, Description, Timeout, MemorySize, Publish, VpcConfig, DeadLetterConfig, Environment, KMSKeyArn

compare that list to what is shown in the boto3 docs and you see that a few things are missing at the end there including tags

I'm in python 2.7 and pip confirms my boto3 is 1.4.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works just fine for me:

```
>>> import boto3
>>> client = boto3.client('lambda')

>>> response=client.create_function(FunctionName='bar', Runtime='python2.7', Handler='index.handler', Tags={'Action': 'Test'}, Role='arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/my-role', Code={'S3Bucket':'my-bucket', 'S3Key':'files.zip'})

>>> client.tag_resource(Resource='arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-2:123456789012:function:bar', Tags={'Food':'Cheese'})
{'ResponseMetadata': {'RetryAttempts': 0, 'HTTPStatusCode': 204, 'RequestId': '93963c42-36d5-11e7-a457-8730520029b8', 'HTTPHeaders': {'date': 'Fri, 12 May 2017 05:40:58 GMT', 'x-amzn-requestid': '93963c42-36d5-11e7-a457-8730520029b8', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'content-type': 'application/json'}}}

>>> client.list_tags(Resource='arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-2:123456789012:function:bar')
{'ResponseMetadata': {'RetryAttempts': 0, 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'RequestId': '9e826957-36d5-11e7-a554-a30d477976ba', 'HTTPHeaders': {'date': 'Fri, 12 May 2017 05:41:16 GMT', 'x-amzn-requestid': '9e826957-36d5-11e7-a554-a30d477976ba', 'content-length': '42', 'content-type': 'application/json', 'connection': 'keep-alive'}}, u'Tags': {u'Action': u'Test', u'Food': u'Cheese'}}
```

Comment: that's odd. could you do me a favor and add a bogus tag to the create method (like taggg) and see if you get the same error message i get above?

Comment: my boto3 was up to date but not my botocore. running pip install -U boto3 fixed things